# В поле ModelChoiceField не удается присвоить начальные данные

Tags: html, python-3.x, json, django, form

В моем приложении пользователь может создавать и редактировать отчеты. При рендеринге страницы редактирования отчета, поля заполняются начальными данными.
Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой - одно из полей (operator) не отображает то значение которое я передаю ему во вьюшке через аргумент initial. Вместо этого поле либо остается пустым, либо принимает дефолтное значение - в зависимости от настроек. Все остальные поля заполняются начальными данными без ошибок.
Я использую наборы форм (Formsets), проблемное поле - поле выбора ModelChoiceField. Начальные данные берутся из json массива.
Насколько я смог разобраться в HTML коде - в проблемном поле operator, в тэге "option"(его вроде бы генерирует виджет Select) не хватает атрибута "selected". Но как этот атрибут туда поместить непонятно. Добавляет путаницы то что поле eq_type, которое также является полем выбора, отображается без ошибок. "selected" в нем появляется напротив нужного варианта.
Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Пожалуйста, подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

*Фрагмент **forms.py**:*

```
class AMSEquipmentForm(forms.Form):
    EQ_TYPES = (
        ('panel_antenna', 'панельная антенна'),
        ('RRL_antenna', 'РРЛ антенна'),
        ('radio_module', 'радиомодуль')
    )
    eq_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=EQ_TYPES, label='Тип')
    height = forms.IntegerField(label='Высота')
    proportions = forms.IntegerField(label='Размеры')
    amount = forms.IntegerField(label='Количество')
    manufacturer = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Производитель')
    model = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Модель')
    operator = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Operator.objects.all(), label='Оператор')  # Проблемное поле
    note = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Примечание')

    eq_type.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'formset-field'})
    height.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'formset-field'})
    proportions.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'formset-field'})
    amount.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'formset-field'})
    manufacturer.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'formset-field'})
    model.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'formset-field'})
    operator.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'formset-field'}) # Проблемное поле
    note.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'formset-field'})
```

*Фрагмент **views.py**:*

```
def report_update(request, pk):
    EquipmentFormset = formset_factory(AMSEquipmentForm, max_num=1)
    report = Report.objects.get(idReport=pk)
    form = ReportModelForm(instance=report)
    formset = EquipmentFormset(initial=json.loads(report.reportEquipAms), prefix='reports_report') # Здесь передаю начальные данные
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportModelForm(request.POST or None)
        formset = EquipmentFormset(request.POST or None, prefix='reports_report')
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            report.reportYear = form.cleaned_data['reportYear']
            report.reportObject_id = form.cleaned_data['reportObject']
            report.reportTemplate_id = form.cleaned_data['reportTemplate']
            report.reportTeam_id = form.cleaned_data['reportTeam']
            report.reportEquipment_id = form.cleaned_data['reportEquipment']
            report.reportWind = form.cleaned_data['reportWind']
            report.reportWeather = form.cleaned_data['reportWeather']
            report.reportSoil = form.cleaned_data['reportSoil']
            report.reportTemp = form.cleaned_data['reportTemp']
            report.reportWeather3 = form.cleaned_data['reportWeather3']
            report.reportElVoltage = form.cleaned_data['reportElVoltage']
            report.reportElCableL = form.cleaned_data['reportElCableL']
            report.reportElCableR = form.cleaned_data['reportElCableR']
            report.reportElRope = form.cleaned_data['reportElRope']
            report.reportElBus = form.cleaned_data['reportElBus']
            report.reportMeasuresDate = form.cleaned_data['reportMeasuresDate']
            report.reportData = form.cleaned_data['reportData']
            report.reportEquipAms = json.dumps(formset.cleaned_data, cls=OperatorEncoder, ensure_ascii=False)
            report.save()
            return redirect('reports:report-list')
    context = {
        'report': report,
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset
    }
    return render(request, "reports/report_update.html", context)
```

*Фрагмент **models.py**:*

```
class Operator(models.Model):
    idOperator = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    operatorName = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    operatorReport = models.ForeignKey("Report", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    operatorContract = models.ForeignKey("Contract",null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.operatorName

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Оператор"
        verbose_name_plural = "Операторы"
```

*Отображение полей в браузере, если смотреть через инспектор кода:*

*поле **eq_type**:*

```
<select name="reports_report-1-eq_type" class="formset-field" id="id_reports_report-1-eq_type">
    <option value="panel_antenna">панельная антенна</option>
    <option value="RRL_antenna" selected>РРЛ антенна</option>
    <option value="radio_module">радиомодуль</option>
</select>
```

*поле **operator**:*

```
<select name="reports_report-1-operator" class="formset-field" id="id_reports_report-1-operator">
    <option value="8">Оператор3</option>
    <option value="9">Оператор2</option>
    <option value="10">Оператор1</option>
</select>
```

*Фрагмент html шаблона, который отвечает за форму:*

```
            {% for equipment in formset %}
                <tr class="item">
                    <td>
                        {{ equipment.eq_type }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ equipment.height }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ equipment.proportions }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ equipment.amount }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ equipment.manufacturer }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ equipment.model }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ equipment.operator }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ equipment.note }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-form-row" id="{{ formset.prefix }}">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

@NKSM подсказал мне в комментариях, что я должен передать первичный ключ объекта Operator в поле «operator». Я передавал туда название объекта.
Переписал OperatorEncoder:

```
class OperatorEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Operator):
            return obj.idOperator
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

и все заработало как нужно.